# do we have any alternative solution for WHERE VALUE IS NOT NULL MySQL Query?

Tags: mysql, node.js, python-3.x

```
CREATE TABLE xyz_table (sensor1 int, sensor2 int);

INSERT INTO xyz_table VALUES
(10, 20),(30, null),(40, 50),(60, null);

Select sensor2 from xyz_table WHERE sensor2 IS NOT NULL;

sensor2
20
50
```

WHERE sensor2 IS NOT NULL -- it is taking more time (for each query around 1.5 seconds).
do we have any alternative solution for this ?

Select sensor2 from xyz_table WHERE sensor2 IS NOT NULL
sensor2
20
50

I have tried above query, it is taking more time to check where condition (1.5 seconds).
do we have any alternative solution for above query. it help me a lot. because in my case I need to query multiple rows to filter not null values.

Comment: Run tme for the published query and data in mysql takes 1.5 seconds isn't credible , is this real data or a sample , if a sample how big is your dB , where is it and can you also publish python and nodejs code.

Comment: *do we have any alternative solution for this ?* Yes. This "alternative" solution is an index creation.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
The above code snippet  is a sample example. actually i am querying thousands of rows. due to that taking more time. 
WHERE sensor2 IS NOT NULL -- without this condition its taking milliseconds. but if use condition taking 1.5 seconds. 

do we have any alternative solution for this ? Yes. This "alternative" solution is an index creation -- Can you please provide any sample query. it will help me a lot

Comment: Could you please provide any solution ?